# Get post text (by its URL) from database dump

Tags: permalinks, database

Given: database dump (no actual site files survived) and a list of posts' URLs from that site.

Is there a simple way to select (from 'posts' table) posts contents (matching them by URL)? There were thousands of posts, and I wouldn't like to do all that searching manually.

Site language is (was) Russian. Permalink structure was '/%postname%/', WP version was between 5.2 and 5.2.4 (db_version options record is 44719).

Comment: Are you planning on doing this in the context of WordPress by restoring the dump and pointing a new install to the DB or are you just connecting to the DB directly through vanilla PHP? Assuming there is one URL on each line of the file, you could loop over the file and pull out the slug from the URL then match this against the post_name field in the wp_posts table. There's also the guid field which _may_ have a full URL match, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: The original text is in Russian. Transliteration to the /%postname%/ isn't a trivial task; scanning the dump manually is out of question, I need automated means.

So the question is, how to do that in absence of working WP installation compatible with DB dump.

Answering your question, I have no other option but connect to DB directly, PHP or otherwise.